# Graph disapear read and write excel file using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Hi I am using  http://phpexcel.codeplex.com for read and write of excel file. I have graph in excel file when i read it and write new data graph disapear. This the example no 7 i.e
07reader.php but change include file from "05featuredemon.php" to "33chartcreate-bar.php"
because i need graph

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

/** Include PHPExcel_IOFactory */
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';


if (!file_exists("33chartcreate-bar.xlsx")) {
exit("Please run 33chartcreate-bar.php first." . EOL);
}

echo date('H:i:s') , " Load from Excel2007 file" , EOL;
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("05featuredemo.xlsx");

 echo date('H:i:s') , " Write to Excel2007 format" , EOL;
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
echo date('H:i:s') , " File written to " , str_replace('.php', '.xlsx',   pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME)) , EOL;


// Echo memory peak usage
 echo date('H:i:s') , " Peak memory usage: " , (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) , " MB" , EOL;

// Echo done
echo date('H:i:s') , " Done writing file" , EOL;
 echo 'File has been created in ' , getcwd() , EOL;
```

please help me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to explicitly tell PHPExcel to read and to write charts

```
$objReader->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
```

and

```
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
```

as shown in the examples

**EDIT**

Explicit spoonfeeding type example

```
//  Create a reader for an Excel2007 file
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
//  Tell the reader to include charts when it loads a file
$objReader->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
//  Load the file
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("33chartcreate-bar.xlsx");


//  Do some stuff to the file


//  Create a writer for an Excel2007 file
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
//  Tell the writer to include any charts when it saves a file
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
//  Save the file
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
```

Comment: If you have any example please give it to me

Comment: There should be several examples in the /Tests directory of the PHPExcel distribution: e.g. 32chartreadwrite.php and 34chartupdate.php

Comment: when i change the xlsx file ie from 32readwrite.xlsx to 33chartcreat-bar.xlsx the chart disappear from it. how it happen

Comment: I don't know how it happened.... my guesses about how you changed it probably won't be accurate

Comment: i only change file name
$inputFileNames = 'templates/32readwrite.xlsx';
to
$inputFileNames = 'templates/32chartcreate-bar.xlsx';

Comment: Does 'templates/32chartcreate-bar.xlsx' actually exist? It isn't a part of the distribution, or created by any of the existing test cases, so where does it come from? Please clarify exactly what you are doing... I try to help, but I have no idea what your code looks like, what files you're working with, what result you're getting... if necessary, re-edit your original question to provide detail.