# Copy charts from (.xls or .xlsx) using PHP

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I am working on a template excel file for some projects and my goal is to populate it with PHP. I create an excel document with two sheets, one is a table with all of the information that I am going to plot, and the second sheet is just a graph that is based on the table from the previous sheet.

Whenever I use (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) PHPSpreadsheet (since PHPExcel is deprecated) I am able to read/write/copy/etc the first sheet, but whenever I try to save the sheet without touching the graph sheet at all, nothing happens. I save the file successfully but when I try to open it I get an error stating that Excel found unreadable content in the file and to repair it. I repair it and the second sheet with the graph is empty.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/382

This is the closest thing I found to my issue, and I did add the setIncludeChart functions, but nothing seems to work.

I also feel that I have exhausted online searches and am now hoping that there is an alternative to PHPSpreadsheet that will allow me to use a chart in a template (supplied) excel file.

```
        $xls = 'KPI_ReadinessTemplate.xls';
        $xlsxTarget = 'NEWX_KPI_ReadinessTemplate.xlsx';
        $xlsTarget = 'NEW_KPI_ReadinessTemplate.xls';

        $inputFileType = 'Xlsx';
        $inputFileName = $xlsx;
        $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $reader->setIncludeCharts(true);
        $spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
        $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $worksheet->getCell('A1')->setValue('Help me');
        $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
        $writer->setIncludeCharts(true);
        $fileData = $writer->save($xlsxTarget);

        $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls();
        $reader->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
        $workbook = $reader->load($xls);
        $writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xls($workbook);
        $writer->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
        $writer->save($xlsTarget);
```

I am expecting the chart to be copied, in the code from above there is no modification of the file, it should be an exact one-to-one copy of the supplied file but it isn't working at all as it seems the graph gets corrupted and I have to repair the excel the next time I open it.

EDIT: I also installed the archived PHPExcel and tried it using [Graph disapear read and write excel file using PHPExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744313/graph-disapear-read-and-write-excel-file-using-phpexcel) and I still had the same issue.

Comment: did you find the soloution?

Comment: @scarletwitch I did not. I ended up manually unzipping my xlsx file and editing the raw XML to modify my chart and cells. It was a pain to work with, and I hope that one day PHPExcel will properly support graphs. I have some more details about what I did in this issue tracker https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/382

Comment: @97WaterPolo How did you manually edit xml file?

Comment: @PrajwalBati xlsx files are just compressed files. If you unzip it within your code you are able to edit the actual .xml files within it to contain whatever information you need. Once you included your info you then zip it back into a .xlsx and it will have all your data. Specifically https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/382#issuecomment-498853879